# How to pass a variable to JSON query string

Tags: json

I've created the following code and want to pass a city name from the drop down which in turn will show the temperature of that city:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>


        $(document).ready(function () {
            document.getElementById('cityName').value;
         //   localStorage.setItem('City_Name', city);

            //-------------------------
            var searchtext = "select item.condition from weather.forecast where woeid in (select woeid from geo.places(1) where text='" + city + "') and u='c'"
            //change city variable dynamically as required
            $.getJSON("https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=" + searchtext + "&format=json").success(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                $('#temp').html("Temperature in " + city + " is " + data.query.results.channel.item.condition.temp + "°C");
              //  localStorage.setItem('tempr', data.query.results.channel.item.condition.temp);
            //-------------------------

            });
        });

</script>
```

When I type the city name manually in the code, it works but fails when I pass the value of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it works for you.
I tried it and its worked

Sample Output

> Temperature in Mumbai is 27°C

Look at this line carefully
you take the city name but you didn't define it with "var"

> var city = document.getElementById('cityName').value;

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var city = document.getElementById('cityName').value;
    //   localStorage.setItem('City_Name', city);

    //-------------------------
    var searchtext = "select item.condition from weather.forecast where woeid in (select woeid from geo.places(1) where text='"+city+"') and u='c'";
    //change city variable dynamically as required
    //https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select item.condition from weather.forecast where woeid in (select woeid from geo.places(1) where text='New York') and u='c'&format=json
    $.getJSON("https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=" + searchtext + "&format=json").success(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        $('#temp').html("Temperature in " + city + " is " + data.query.results.channel.item.condition.temp + "°C");
        //  localStorage.setItem('tempr', data.query.results.channel.item.condition.temp);
        //-------------------------

    });
});
```